# Is it strange to call food the means to achieve a purpose?

Tags: vocabulary

I guess the following is grammatically correct.

> Patricia is a chef. She is preparing the food for tomorrow's party.

The preposition "for" indicates the **reason** of her preparing, which is the party.

I guess I could also consider the party the **purpose**. In contrast, What should I called the food? Is it strange to call food the **means** to achieve a purpose? Are there any other nouns, which relate to "purpose" or "reason", could be used here?

Comment: Are you asking about the preposition or the noun? Have you looked at the senses of *for* in a dictionary and not found any that make sense? Is the woman a chef or a murderer trying to poison someone? What noun other than *food* did you have in mind? You seem to be asking multiple questions, but none of them are providing enough information to understand what you're actually asking. Try focusing on a single question, and expanding on the context and confusion.

Comment: I'm preparing food.  Why am I preparing food?  Because of a party.  Therefore I am preparing food for a party.  Makes sense.  There is an unspoken implication or assumption that parties require food, and it's common to leave those assumptions implied and unspoken if the speaker/writer believe the listener/reader would make the same assumptions.  For food to be the *means* to a party, that would mean you'd be able to setup a buffet and be able to call it party.  Honestly, it would probably work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't unusual at all, it seems like you have only noted one of the dictionary definitions of "for". The one that is pertinent here is:

> :as being or constituting
>   *eg. "eggs for breakfast"*

The food is *for* the party in the sense that it is *a part* of the party.

You might also say:

> Patricia is a chef. She is preparing the party food for tomorrow.

This is because the party is *part* of tomorrow's events.